# Не работает nmp ci

Tags: gulp, npm

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста, пытаюсь сделать сборку проекта, видео на ютубе 2-х годовалой давности, скачал сборку галпа у учителя, и пытаюсь установить пакеты в свою сборку, но вводя в терминал, находясь в папке проекта мне выдает такую ошибку. Автор использует npm ci, но так же я пробовал npm i, ошибка так же не покидает мой проект... Потратил час, но так и не понял в чем проблема.

```
salute@salute-desktop:/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic$ npm install
npm WARN deprecated ini@1.3.5: Please update to ini >=1.3.6 to avoid a prototype pollution issue
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.3: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.6: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.3.2: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.2: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.0: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated axios@0.19.0: Critical security vulnerability fixed in v0.21.1. For more information, see https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3410
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /home/salute/.nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/bin/node /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/home/salute/.nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.15.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:208:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:208:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:208:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:208:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:484:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:406:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at F (/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:68:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at E (/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:208:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.19.0-46-generic
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/home/salute/.nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/bin/node" "/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.15.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/salute/.npm/_logs/2023-06-29T12_53_12_597Z-debug-0.log
```

Попробовал npm update, выдает теперь такие ошибки

```
    salute@salute-desktop:/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic$ npm update
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /home/salute/.nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/bin/node /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/home/salute/.nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.15.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:208:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:208:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:208:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:208:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:484:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:406:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at F (/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:68:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at E (/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:208:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.19.0-46-generic
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/home/salute/.nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/bin/node" "/var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/Вёрстка/Mavic/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.15.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/salute/.npm/_logs/2023-06-29T13_55_16_677Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: **deprecated == устаревший** и у вас в названии директории присутствует `Вёрстка`, возможно (не всегда) из-за этого могут быть проблемы) попробуйте `npm update`

Comment: Обновил, посмотрите сейчас что у меня, пожалуйста

Comment: [Node.js: Python not found exception due to node-sass and node-gyp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45801457/node-js-python-not-found-exception-due-to-node-sass-and-node-gyp). Но сам по себе node-sass [устарел](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#node-sass)

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил установкой Gulp глобально на свой компьютер, через терминал VS Code, и установил Gulp в проект путём npm i gulp --save-dev, и уже после ввёл npm ci